# Three Column Layout using float

Tags: css

How would I go about a three column layout to keep the background image from collapsing and get everything aligned to the top. I've got it almost right, but my ads keep falling below everything else. Could it be because I've got the #content as an inline block? I need testimonials on the left, content in the center, and ads to the right. Plus have the background image still visible.

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="inner-wrapper">
<div id="content">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eleifend mi eu tellus vulputate hendrerit. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas viverra, turpis sit amet semper mattis, lectus arcu viverra enim, et euismod sapien augue eu risus. Cras feugiat dapibus viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum sodales tincidunt neque, eu gravida nibh feugiat sed. Ut lorem mauris, aliquam eu quam at, congue ultrices leo. Vivamus at aliquam magna, vitae malesuada enim. Donec semper justo magna, adipiscing rutrum magna pellentesque non. Sed condimentum ultricies suscipit. Vestibulum auctor accumsan risus, nec commodo nulla ultricies ac. Vestibulum pharetra consectetur nunc id ultricies. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt vulputate. Praesent ultrices nunc est, vitae facilisis erat posuere eu.</p>
</div>

<div id="testimonials">
<h2>What My Clients Say</h2>
<p>Sed sit amet nibh iaculis, lacinia diam nec, mollis tellus. Nunc fringilla est nec tellus porttitor ornare. Donec venenatis justo eu lacus interdum interdum a quis justo. Integer et diam vitae neque consectetur bibendum eu non dui. Etiam eu aliquet justo, sed mattis nibh. Mauris fringilla accumsan urna, at pulvinar ligula dignissim vel. Aenean posuere mi sit amet convallis pellentesque.</p>
</div>
</div><!-- end #inner-wrapper -->

<div id="ads">
<h2>Ads</h2>
<p>Fusce faucibus facilisis est. Praesent a purus adipiscing, varius turpis in, malesuada risus. Vivamus ornare diam odio, ut elementum magna pretium a. Etiam porta diam elit, egestas pharetra erat mollis vel. Donec ut mauris sit amet tortor porta sollicitudin. Sed ultricies mattis semper. In nec quam eget nibh pellentesque bibendum a ut libero. Nulla id risus viverra, varius felis eget, interdum odio. Phasellus venenatis blandit sem, hendrerit vehicula sem luctus quis.</p>
</div>

</div><!-- end #wrapper -->
</body>
```

CSS: (thus far)

```
#wrapper{background-image: url(images/columns-195-570-195.png);
width: 960px;
align-content: center;}

#testimonials{
    float: left;
    width: 195px;
}

#content{
  display: inline-block; 
    width:570px; 
}

#ads{
    float: right;
    width: 195px;}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the typo in the title... it's early.

Comment: Have you cleared the floats? Also `align-content` only works for `flexbox`. I think you mean `text-align:center`.

Comment: why are you using floats.. look into flexbox .. much nicer :) (just a tipp)

Comment: Because it's for a school assignment and I have to : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here you can find both solutions. A solution with floating (you need it) and a solution with flexbox.

**Solution only with floating**

```css
#wrapper{
    align-content:center;
    background-image: url(images/columns-195-570-195.png);
    width: 960px;
}
#testimonials{
    float:left;
    width:195px;
}
#inner-wrapper {
    float:left;
}
#content {
    display:inline-block; 
    width:570px; 
}
#ads {
    float:left;
    width:195px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eleifend mi eu tellus vulputate hendrerit. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas viverra, turpis sit amet semper mattis, lectus arcu viverra enim, et euismod sapien augue eu risus. Cras feugiat dapibus viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum sodales tincidunt neque, eu gravida nibh feugiat sed. Ut lorem mauris, aliquam eu quam at, congue ultrices leo. Vivamus at aliquam magna, vitae malesuada enim. Donec semper justo magna, adipiscing rutrum magna pellentesque non. Sed condimentum ultricies suscipit. Vestibulum auctor accumsan risus, nec commodo nulla ultricies ac. Vestibulum pharetra consectetur nunc id ultricies. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt vulputate. Praesent ultrices nunc est, vitae facilisis erat posuere eu.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="testimonials">
            <h2>What My Clients Say</h2>
            <p>Sed sit amet nibh iaculis, lacinia diam nec, mollis tellus. Nunc fringilla est nec tellus porttitor ornare. Donec venenatis justo eu lacus interdum interdum a quis justo. Integer et diam vitae neque consectetur bibendum eu non dui. Etiam eu aliquet justo, sed mattis nibh. Mauris fringilla accumsan urna, at pulvinar ligula dignissim vel. Aenean posuere mi sit amet convallis pellentesque.</p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end #inner-wrapper -->
    <div id="ads">
        <h2>Ads</h2>
        <p>Fusce faucibus facilisis est. Praesent a purus adipiscing, varius turpis in, malesuada risus. Vivamus ornare diam odio, ut elementum magna pretium a. Etiam porta diam elit, egestas pharetra erat mollis vel. Donec ut mauris sit amet tortor porta sollicitudin. Sed ultricies mattis semper. In nec quam eget nibh pellentesque bibendum a ut libero. Nulla id risus viverra, varius felis eget, interdum odio. Phasellus venenatis blandit sem, hendrerit vehicula sem luctus quis.</p>
    </div>
</div><!-- end #wrapper -->
```

**Solution with flexbox**

```css
#wrapper{
    align-content:center;
    background-image:url(images/columns-195-570-195.png);
    display:flex;
    width:960px;
}
#testimonials{
    width:195px;
}
#content{
    width:570px; 
}
#ads {
    width:195px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="testimonials">
        <h2>What My Clients Say</h2>
        <p>Sed sit amet nibh iaculis, lacinia diam nec, mollis tellus. Nunc fringilla est nec tellus porttitor ornare. Donec venenatis justo eu lacus interdum interdum a quis justo. Integer et diam vitae neque consectetur bibendum eu non dui. Etiam eu aliquet justo, sed mattis nibh. Mauris fringilla accumsan urna, at pulvinar ligula dignissim vel. Aenean posuere mi sit amet convallis pellentesque.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eleifend mi eu tellus vulputate hendrerit. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas viverra, turpis sit amet semper mattis, lectus arcu viverra enim, et euismod sapien augue eu risus. Cras feugiat dapibus viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum sodales tincidunt neque, eu gravida nibh feugiat sed. Ut lorem mauris, aliquam eu quam at, congue ultrices leo. Vivamus at aliquam magna, vitae malesuada enim. Donec semper justo magna, adipiscing rutrum magna pellentesque non. Sed condimentum ultricies suscipit. Vestibulum auctor accumsan risus, nec commodo nulla ultricies ac. Vestibulum pharetra consectetur nunc id ultricies. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt vulputate. Praesent ultrices nunc est, vitae facilisis erat posuere eu.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ads">
        <h2>Ads</h2>
        <p>Fusce faucibus facilisis est. Praesent a purus adipiscing, varius turpis in, malesuada risus. Vivamus ornare diam odio, ut elementum magna pretium a. Etiam porta diam elit, egestas pharetra erat mollis vel. Donec ut mauris sit amet tortor porta sollicitudin. Sed ultricies mattis semper. In nec quam eget nibh pellentesque bibendum a ut libero. Nulla id risus viverra, varius felis eget, interdum odio. Phasellus venenatis blandit sem, hendrerit vehicula sem luctus quis.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't need the wrappers or floats to get a working three-column-layout.

Comment: Well, this kept my background image from vanishing, however the content isn't centered and my ads aren't on the right like I need them to be. Can I not add floats to place everything where it needs to go?

Comment: @Sylvia585 do you mean you need the ADS always at the right most position? Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/er4h0e95/1/ Please let me know thanks.

Comment: Regarding the use of flexibox, it could be problematic on older version of IE, keep an eye on browser support and check if match your specification http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @GibboK Somewhat yes, However testimonials and heading need to swap. I've got it lined up correctly now.. BUT my background image vanished... Ugh.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch this worked correctly to line everything up, but why did the background image vanish?

Comment: @Sylvia585 I swapped testimonials with heading, please let me know if it is correct, look here https://jsfiddle.net/er4h0e95/3/ ... Could you please a edit my jsfiddle with your background image, I am sure we can fix it too ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92861/discussion-between-sylvia585-and-gibbok).

Comment: Please have a look here, it should solve your issue, please let me know https://jsfiddle.net/er4h0e95/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `float: left;` on each column, you can add (if necessary) a `float: clear;` on your latest column.

Regarding your issue with the image, you need to set the size and position for the wrapper div.

Example also visible here: https://jsfiddle.net/er4h0e95/6/

```css
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg);
    width: 960px;
    height:100%;
    align-content: center;
}
#testimonials {
    float: left;
    width: 195px;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width:570px;
}
#ads {
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 195px;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="testimonials">
                
<h2>What My Clients Say</h2>

                <p>Sed sit amet nibh iaculis, lacinia diam nec, mollis tellus. Nunc fringilla est nec tellus porttitor ornare. Donec venenatis justo eu lacus interdum interdum a quis justo. Integer et diam vitae neque consectetur bibendum eu non dui. Etiam eu aliquet justo, sed mattis nibh. Mauris fringilla accumsan urna, at pulvinar ligula dignissim vel. Aenean posuere mi sit amet convallis pellentesque.</p>
            </div>
            
<h1>Heading</h1>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eleifend mi eu tellus vulputate hendrerit. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas viverra, turpis sit amet semper mattis, lectus arcu viverra enim, et euismod sapien augue eu risus. Cras feugiat dapibus viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum sodales tincidunt neque, eu gravida nibh feugiat sed. Ut lorem mauris, aliquam eu quam at, congue ultrices leo. Vivamus at aliquam magna, vitae malesuada enim. Donec semper justo magna, adipiscing rutrum magna pellentesque non. Sed condimentum ultricies suscipit. Vestibulum auctor accumsan risus, nec commodo nulla ultricies ac. Vestibulum pharetra consectetur nunc id ultricies. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt vulputate. Praesent ultrices nunc est, vitae facilisis erat posuere eu.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #inner-wrapper -->
    <div id="ads">
        
<h2>Ads</h2>

        <p>Fusce faucibus facilisis est. Praesent a purus adipiscing, varius turpis in, malesuada risus. Vivamus ornare diam odio, ut elementum magna pretium a. Etiam porta diam elit, egestas pharetra erat mollis vel. Donec ut mauris sit amet tortor porta sollicitudin. Sed ultricies mattis semper. In nec quam eget nibh pellentesque bibendum a ut libero. Nulla id risus viverra, varius felis eget, interdum odio. Phasellus venenatis blandit sem, hendrerit vehicula sem luctus quis.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end #wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the order of `testimonials` and `content` div's in HTML, it will work fine. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mn4rs5g/)**

```
#testimonials {
    float: left;
    width: 195px;
}
#content {
    display: inline-block;
    width:570px;
}
#ads {
    float: right;
    width: 195px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="testimonials">.. </div>

<div id="content">..</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner-wrapper is creating a div displaying testimonials and content as block that is pushing the ads to a new line. Either move the end div to contain all three sections, or display the inner-wrapper and ads as inline-block so they line up correctly.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
        <div id="content">            
            <h1>Heading</h1> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eleifend mi eu tellus vulputate hendrerit. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas viverra, turpis sit amet semper mattis, lectus arcu viverra enim, et euismod sapien augue eu risus. Cras feugiat dapibus viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum sodales tincidunt neque, eu gravida nibh feugiat sed. Ut lorem mauris, aliquam eu quam at, congue ultrices leo. Vivamus at aliquam magna, vitae malesuada enim. Donec semper justo magna, adipiscing rutrum magna pellentesque non. Sed condimentum ultricies suscipit. Vestibulum auctor accumsan risus, nec commodo nulla ultricies ac. Vestibulum pharetra consectetur nunc id ultricies. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt vulputate. Praesent ultrices nunc est, vitae facilisis erat posuere eu.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="testimonials">
            <h2>What My Clients Say</h2>   
            <p>Sed sit amet nibh iaculis, lacinia diam nec, mollis tellus. Nunc fringilla est nec tellus porttitor ornare. Donec venenatis justo eu lacus interdum interdum a quis justo. Integer et diam vitae neque consectetur bibendum eu non dui. Etiam eu aliquet justo, sed mattis nibh. Mauris fringilla accumsan urna, at pulvinar ligula dignissim vel. Aenean posuere mi sit amet convallis pellentesque.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="ads">              
            <h2>Ads</h2>   
            <p>Fusce faucibus facilisis est. Praesent a purus adipiscing, varius turpis in, malesuada risus. Vivamus ornare diam odio, ut elementum magna pretium a. Etiam porta diam elit, egestas pharetra erat mollis vel. Donec ut mauris sit amet tortor porta sollicitudin. Sed ultricies mattis semper. In nec quam eget nibh pellentesque bibendum a ut libero. Nulla id risus viverra, varius felis eget, interdum odio. Phasellus venenatis blandit sem, hendrerit vehicula sem luctus quis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #inner-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- end #wrapper -->
```

To center content add:

```
#wrapper {
    background-image: url(images/columns-195-570-195.png);
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```